# Error when passing friend class as type from public class to friend base class

Tags: vb.net, generics, inheritance, user-controls

Disclaimer: I am fairly new to working with generics so I am not entirely sure if what I am trying to do even makes sense or is possible.

I have a bunch of user controls in a project. All of these user controls share a similar property so I want to move it into a base class. The only difference is the return type of the property.

I have three classes interacting in this scenario. The first class is a base type, which inherits from `CompositeControl` and will be inherited by other classes in my project:

```
Friend Class MyBaseClass(Of T As {New})
    Inherits CompositeControl

    Private _someProperty As T = Nothing

    Protected ReadOnly Property SomeProperty As T
        Get
            // dumbed down for the sake of example
            If _someProperty Is Nothing Then
                _someProperty = New T()
            End If

            Return _someProperty 
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Then I have this control class, which inherits from `MyBaseClass`:

```
Public Class MyControlClass
    Inherits MyBaseClass(Of MyReturnTypeClass)

    // snip...
End Class
```

And finally `MyReturnTypeClass` which is what the base's `SomeProperty` should return:

```
Friend Class MyReturnTypeClass
    Public Property AutoProperty1 As Boolean = False
    Public Property AutoProperty2 As String = String.Empty
    // etc
End Class
```

When I attempt to build the project, I get this error from `MyControlClass`:

> Inconsistent accessibility: type argument 'MyReturnTypeClass' is less accessible than Class 'MyControlClass'.

I need `MyControlClass` to be `Public` so it can be consumed by other projects, and I also want the `MyBaseClass` and `MyReturnTypeClass` to be `Friend` so they cannot be seen/used by consumers. Am I just missing some special keyword somewhere or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inherit from a base class that is less accessible than the derived class.  So for instance, this won't work:

```
Friend Class MyBase
End Class

Public Class MyDerived
    Inherits MyBase  ' Won't compile because MyBase is less accessible
End Class
```

Therefore, since in your example, `MyBaseClass(T)` has is a friend type, but you are trying to  inherit from it into a public `MyControlClass` type.  Therefore, even if you took generics and `MyReturnTypeClass` out of the "equation", it still wouldn't work.

However, with generics, even if no member of the public interface of the class actually uses the generic type, the type must still be at least as accessible as the derived type.  For instance:

```
Public Class MyBase(Of T)
    ' T not actually used at all
End Class

Friend Class MyOtherType
End Class

Public Class MyDerived
    Inherits MyBase(MyOtherType)  ' Won't compile because MyOtherType is less accessible
End Class
```

Comment: this explains why the code I have will not compile, but does not provide any alternatives? do I have no other choice than marking `MyReturnTypeClass` as `Public`?

Comment: Yes, if it is going to be a base class for a public derived class, then it must also be public.  As channs pointed out, you could add the MustInherit modifier to the base class so that other projects couldn't  use it directly.

Answer (score 2):

The base class must be at least as accessible as the derived class. This is a language restriction (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx03xt0t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

If you intend to avoid `MyBaseClass` being instantiated by consumers, consider marking it `Public MustInherit` instead of `Friend`. Hope this helps.